# Asp.net mvc deployment 500 - Internal server error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, office-interop

I have a asp.net MVC application i am getting 500 - Internal server error. My code is working fine what i have figured out is whenever i am initializing the Microsoft word class then i am getting this error if i remove the initialization part then it works fine any suggestion??

```
 //Create new instance of word and create a new document
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
               // Word.Document doc = null;

                //Properties for the new word document, so everything happens in the background. If this isn’t set all the word documents will be visible
               // object readOnly = false;
               // object isVisible = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be missing  `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll` or its dependent file from your deployment.

You can get detailed error message by disabling `customErrors`  in `web.config` file of deployment

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: i have copied all references still the same problem

Comment: what is the error you are getting after disabling customerror?

Comment: 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

Comment: by default the ASPNET users does not have permissions to com, so  assign User ASPNET with the permissions with required permission

Comment: i have created a new user Service and assigned all the permission but in DCON config i cannot find Microsoft word

Comment: make sure MS word is installed on the machine

Comment: its installed but still the same problem